# Use NetConnectionID name to populate selection list in batch

Tags: batch-file, wmi

I have written a simple Batch file to manage the IP addresses of the Various NICs on my PCs. Currently though it needs to have the names of the NICs written into the batch file so they can be selected:

```
ECHO  Select Network Interface                          
ECHO.                                                             
ECHO   1 - WiFi                                 
ECHO   2 - LAN 1                                    
ECHO   3 - LAN 2                                            
ECHO   9 - Exit                                                   
SET "A="
SET /P A=Set Your Choice And Press Enter: 
IF "%A%"=="1" set net_int=WiFi
IF "%A%"=="2" set net_int=LAN 1
IF "%A%"=="3" set net_int=LAN 2
IF "%A%"=="9" EXIT
echo %net_int% selected
```

I have found the following snippet to list the network connections available on a PC:

```
@Echo Off
Set "i=0"
For /F "Skip=1Delims=" %%A In (
'WMIC NIC  Get NetConnectionID'
) Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do Call :Sub %%B
Set NIC[
Timeout -1
Exit/B
:Sub
Set/A i+=1
Set "NIC[%i%]=%*"
```

Is it possible to use something like this to 'populate' the Select Network Interface list in my Batch file, with the number of entries in the list matching the number of NICs available? I wish to use this on several machines, without having to edit the Batch to reflect the names and number of NICs on each machine.

Comment: Yes but it depends on your specific requirements, many of the devices returned you may not have realised you had and many may not be enabled or connected. It may be better if you expand on the task a little, so that we know what you're intending to do with the results. _BTW, that snippet looks remarkably like mine!_

Comment: I found the snippet on here somewhere whilst searching for solutions to this, if it is yours it works great, thanks very much! When I run it on my machines it returns the wifi NIC and the various Lan adapters installed. At work I frequently need to change IP address, subnet mask etc for the various NICs attached to the PC. The batch file I use allows me to do this. What I am seeking to do is automate collecting the NIC names and placing them into a list without having to edit the batch file to reflect the names and number of NICs attached to each PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick! - What we are doing here is pretty simple. Based on your snippet, I tweaked it to show the names without empty lines. From there, we use a count string to count each result in `+1`. - Using this number, we can make a unique string out of it!

In the example: `Set "Num!i!=%%B"` - We are taking `Num` Plus `!i!` (`Num1, Num2, Num3, Exc`) to equal `%%B` (The `NetConnectionID`). Simple right! - See where we are taking this yet?

Now that we can assign each `NetConnectionID` a number and unique string, we echo this with `Echo   !i! - %%B` as the format you posted. This list will grow with numbers `1-Infin` for as many `NetConnectionID`'s present on your device or network.

**Example:**

```
Select Network Interface

  1 - Bluetooth Network Connection
  2 - Ethernet
  3 - Wi-Fi
  4 - VPN - VPN Client
  5 - Hamachi
  6 - Ethernet 2
  7 - VirtualBox Host-Only Network
  0 - Exit

Set Your Choice And Press Enter:
```

From this, If you have not yet figured out, when choosing a number with `set /P`, we use an set command to set the string `input` as `Num#`. - *BUT* We use `%Input%` to get the unique `#`. This will be setting `Input=!Num1!, Input=!Num2!, Input=!Num3!, Exc!`.

```
Set "INPUT=!Num%INPUT%!"
```

From here we simply clean the string up and you're set to go!

**GetUniqueNetConnectionList.bat:**

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@goto MenuList

:MenuList
cls

Set "INPUT="
Set "i=0"

Echo Select Network Interface  
Echo(

Rem | Get NetConnectionID To String
For /F "Tokens=* Skip=1" %%A In ('WMIC NIC Get NetConnectionID') Do (

    Rem | Remove Empty Lines
    For /F "Tokens=*" %%B In ("%%A") Do (

        Rem | Set Strings
        Set /A "i+=1"

        Rem | Save Variable As String
        Set "Num!i!=%%B"

        Rem | Print String To Console
        Echo   !i! - %%B

    )
)
Echo   0 - Exit

Echo(
Set /P INPUT=Set Your Choice And Press Enter: 
IF /I "!INPUT!"=="0" GOTO :EOF

Rem | Check For Valid Listing
IF /I "!Num%INPUT%!"=="" (

    Rem | Number Not Listed!
    Echo(
    Echo ERROR: Number Was Not On The List.

    Pause>NUL
    goto MenuList

)

cls

Rem | Set String Based On Number
Set "INPUT=!Num%INPUT%!"

Rem | Remove Spaces From End Of String
for /l %%A in (1,1,100) do (if "!INPUT:~-1!"==" " set INPUT=!INPUT:~0,-1!)
Set "net_int=!INPUT!"

Echo !net_int! Selected
pause
```

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks to feedback on the script, I forgot about a safely net (Mistakes happen) for when or if you choose a number not on the list, it will continue and run the script. This can cause big problems depending on what you use it for being that the string will be empty.

To fix this I simply added a `IF` statement bellow the `set /P` to look for a result. If no valid result was found it will bring you back to the menu.

```
IF /I "!Num%INPUT%!"=="" (

    Echo(
    Echo ERROR: Number Was Not On The List.

    Pause>NUL
    goto MenuList

)
```

---

For help on any of the commands do the following:

- `call /?`
- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `find /?`
- So on.

Comment: I don't think that this is far away, at first glance though it looks as if I select numbers not listed in the menu, they will be accepted without question.

Comment: @Compo Thanks for the feedback. I added a safety-net to the script. User mistakes happen, having the script continue could cause problems.

Comment: That's better, _although I'd suggest that you change the single quotes to doublequotes, i.e. `IF /I "!INPUT!"=="0"` and similarly `IF /I "!Num%INPUT%!"==""`_.

Comment: @Compo It was like that. Formatting issue. EDIT: I think its fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for your help and detailed explanation, this works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test this, *as I don't have access to a Windows PC*, but here's an answer which I've tried to keep not too dissimilar to the snippet you've posted.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('"(Set NIC[) 2>Nul"') Do Set "%%A="
Set "i=0"
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    'WMIC NIC Where "NetConnectionID Is Not Null" Get NetConnectionID'
) Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do Call :Sub %%B
If %i% Equ 1 (Set "NIC[X]=%NIC[1]%") Else Call :Menu
Rem Your commands here
Echo You selected %NIC[X]%
Pause
Exit /B

:Sub
Set /A i+=1
Set "NIC[%i%]=%*"
Exit /B

:Menu
For /L %%A In (1,1,%i%) Do (Echo %%A. !NIC[%%A]!)
Set /P "NIC[X]=Select a network interface from the above list: "
If Not Defined NIC[%NIC[X]%] (ClS & GoTo Menu)
Set "NIC[X]=!NIC[%NIC[X]%]!"
```

*Note: I have deliberately not included the exit option in the menu*